# Custom Translation Component exports function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, internationalization

I'm writing my own component for i18n. It's called Translate and are connected to the redux store, where my translations reside.

I know there are i18n libraries out there but I want to avoid HOC as it makes it difficult to write tests for the app.

This is it (I'm using Typescript):

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import IStoreState from '../../store/IStoreState'
import { LocalizationData } from '../../apiTypes/localizationData'
import { Translation } from '../../apiTypes/translation'

interface IProps {
  localizationData: LocalizationData | null
  context: string
  options?: Translation
  fallback?: string
}

class Translate extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
  public render() {
    const { localizationData, context, options, fallback } = this.props
    return <span>{localizationData && this.translate(context, options, fallback)}</span>
  }

  public translate = (context: string, options?: Translation, fallback?: string): string => {
    const { localizationData } = this.props

    if (localizationData) {
      let res: string = localizationData.translations![context]
      if (options && res && res) {
        // replace optional strings
        for (const key in options) {
          if (options.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            res = res.replace(`%${key}`, options[key] + '')
          }
        }
      }
      // fallback to fallback string OR last segment of translation key
      if (!res) {
        res = fallback || context.substr(context.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
      }
      return res
    }
    return ''
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: IStoreState) {
  return {
    localizationData: state.localizationData,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Translate)
```

It's used like this:

```
import './components/Translate'

public render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Translate context="page.title" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This works fine but I would like to be able to use it as a function as well to be able to do things like:

```
public render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img alt={t('image.title')}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Two options I see:

1. Change `<Translate />` into a function stateless component. Then, return a string instead of a span.

FSC Translate:

```
import translate from '../../services/translate';

const Translate = props => {
    const { localizationData, context, options, fallback } = props;
    return localizationData && translate(context, options, fallback)
};

function mapStateToProps(state: IStoreState) {
    return {
        localizationData: state.localizationData,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Translate)
```

This would change your usage to something like:

```
import './components/Translate'

public render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span><Translate context="page.title" /></span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But it would also allow you to call your component as a function that returns a string:

```
public render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img alt={Translate({ context: 'image.title' })}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. Or even better, abstract the `translate` function out of the component and store it in a separate file that can be used anywhere.

Then `<Translate />` becomes:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import IStoreState from '../../store/IStoreState'
import { LocalizationData } from '../../apiTypes/localizationData'
import { Translation } from '../../apiTypes/translation'
import translate from '../../services/translate';

interface IProps {
  localizationData: LocalizationData | null
  context: string
  options?: Translation
  fallback?: string
}

class Translate extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
  public render() {
    const { localizationData, context, options, fallback } = this.props
    return <span>{localizationData && translate(context, options, fallback, localizationData)}</span>
  }

function mapStateToProps(state: IStoreState) {
  return {
    localizationData: state.localizationData,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Translate)
```

translate.js

```
const translate = (context: string, options?: Translation, fallback?: string, localizationData: object): string => {
    if (localizationData) {
      let res: string = localizationData.translations![context]
      if (options && res && res) {
        // replace optional strings
        for (const key in options) {
          if (options.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            res = res.replace(`%${key}`, options[key] + '')
          }
        }
      }
      // fallback to fallback string OR last segment of translation key
      if (!res) {
        res = fallback || context.substr(context.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
      }
      return res
    }
    return ''
  }

export default translate;
```

Comment: But I don't have props in the in connected service function translate... so props.localizationData isn't available.

Comment: Returning a string doesn't allow me to call the component at a function. Can you provide code?

Comment: @olefrank I don't know TypeScript, but updated answer to better explain. Translate would need to be converted into a functional stateless component. I also fixed `translate.js` to not look at props. You'll just need to pass in `localizationData` as an argument. You'll have to manually pass in each argument since it's just a function and not a component anymore.

Comment: It's not possible to make a component return a string. Also it's anti pattern to connect a Stateless component

Comment: @olefrank It's absolutely possible to just return a string. Here is a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkysmsqz/4/. Remember that all a stateless component is is just a function. It can be called as a normal function OR as a React component. As far as connecting, you should pass the needed props to `Translate` instead of subscribing to the store.